# Can the Spring Cloud Config Server also push config updates to the remote git repo?

Tags: java, spring, git, spring-cloud

After the spring cloud config server clones the git repo and is properly serving up the files, can it also make changes to those files and push them back to the remote git repo? Or would that functionality have to be written in the application running the config server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't write. Config Server is a read only client of the remote git repository.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else interested, I autowired the Spring JGitEnvironmentRepository and wrapped some additional functionality.  I used FileUtils to handle the file ops, and then wrote a basic service using that JGit bean:

```
@Autowired private JGitEnvironmentRepository jgit;

@Value("${spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri}.git")
private String remoteRepoURL;

@Value("${spring.cloud.config.server.git.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${spring.cloud.config.server.git.password}")
private String password;

private Git git = null;
private Repository localRepo ;
private CredentialsProvider creds;

public File getWorkingDirectory(){
    return jgit.getBasedir();
}

public void updateLocalRepo() throws Exception {
    log.info("Updating the local repository.");
    init();
    git.pull()
        .setCredentialsProvider( creds )
        .call();
}

public void commitAndPushRepository(String commitMessage) throws Exception {
    init();
    git.commit()
        .setAll(true)
        .setMessage(commitMessage)
        .call();

    git.push()
        .setCredentialsProvider( creds )
        .call();

    log.info("Pushed local repository with message [" + commitMessage+"].");
}//end commitAndPush

private void init() throws IOException {
    if(git!=null) return;

    String repoPath = jgit.getBasedir().getPath();
    localRepo = new FileRepository(repoPath + "/.git");
    git = new Git(localRepo);
    StoredConfig config = git.getRepository().getConfig();
    config.setString("remote", "origin", "url", remoteRepoURL);
    config.save();
    creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(username, password);
    log.info("Initialized local repository at path " + repoPath);
}
```

---

And here is the file service:

```
@Autowired private GitService gitService;

public void updateFile(String author, String fileName, String newContent) throws Exception{
    Assert.hasLength(fileName, "File name must not be null.");
    Assert.hasLength(newContent, "File must contain content.");
    Assert.hasLength(author, "Unable to update file without author logging.");

    gitService.updateLocalRepo();

    File workingDirectory = gitService.getWorkingDirectory();

    log.info("Updating file [" + fileName + "] in the working dir " + workingDirectory);

    File matchingFile = findFileWithName(workingDirectory, fileName);
    Assert.notNull(matchingFile, "No file with name " + fileName + " was found.");

    FileUtils.write(matchingFile, newContent);
    gitService.commitAndPushRepository( buildCommitMessage(author, fileName) );
}//end updateFile

public String getConfigFileContents(String fileName) throws Exception {
    gitService.updateLocalRepo();
    File file = findFileWithName(gitService.getWorkingDirectory(), fileName);
    Assert.notNull(file, "No file with name " + fileName + " found.");
    return FileUtils.readFileToString( file );
}

public Collection<String> getAllConfigFileNames() throws Exception{
    gitService.updateLocalRepo();
    Collection<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
    Collection<File> allFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(gitService.getWorkingDirectory(), TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
    for(File file : allFiles) {
        fileNames.add(file.getName());
    }//end foreach file

    return fileNames;
}

private String buildCommitMessage(String author, String fileName) {
    return "Author of commit on [" + fileName + "]: " + author;
}

private File findFileWithName(File workingDirectory, String fileName) {
    Collection<File> allFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(workingDirectory, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
    for(File file : allFiles) {
        if(fileName.equals(file.getName())){
            return file;
        }//endif found
    }//end foreach file

    return null;
}//end findFileWIthName
```

Comment: I was weighing up doing something like this over switching to the JDBC backed EnvironmentRepository. I think this gives more traceability and flexibility compared to using a JDBC backend

Comment: @user2153465 that's exactly why I did this. i wanted the commit history readily available without building infrastructure to log events, as well as being able to fork/pull the available repos.